# Xcode 10.1 craches on startup within virtual container

Tags: xcode, macos, vmware, macos-mojave

I'm a new one in the Mac world and currently I'm trying to run Xcode 10.1 within the vmware container with Mac OS X 10.14.

I was able to successfully install Xcode from the AppStore...but can't start Xcode itself. It crashed after initial window (aka, Create a new project...) with full stack trace:

```
Process:               Xcode [626]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               10.1 (14460.46)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks_Fall2018-14460046000000000~5
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       828917606
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [626]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-11-02 13:55:14.216 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14 (18A293u)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        D2FB79AD-8219-9107-CB64-93B01CB6F4C5

Sleep/Wake UUID:       C189A821-D94E-4E2B-98A8-2B12B39649D7

Time Awake Since Boot: 1500 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Sending newProject: to <IDEApplicationCommands: 0x7fe071a42100> from (null)
ProductBuildVersion: 10B61
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): +[NSColor detailAccentColor]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff9cc3c0a8
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Sending newProject: to <IDEApplicationCommands: 0x7fe071a42100> from (null)
  1: Sending openNewProjectAssistant: to <IDEWelcomeWindowController: 0x7fe0712418e0> from <IDEWelcomeWindowHighlightButton: 0x7fe0727649f0>
Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   __CFExceptionProem (in CoreFoundation)
  4   ___forwarding___ (in CoreFoundation)
  5   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)

 64   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 65   main (in Xcode)
 66   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInvalidArgumentException

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff420984ee __exceptionPreprocess + 197
1   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010eed98c2 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 274
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6e07576b objc_exception_throw + 48

64  AppKit                              0x00007fff3f589c26 NSApplicationMain + 780
65  Xcode                               0x000000010ec4682e main + 574
66  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6efebee1 start + 1

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6f15beb6 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f1f9088 pthread_kill + 285
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff6f0a8189 abort + 127
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000110b25793 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1324

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
  com.apple.dt.Xcode (10.1 - 14460.46)
  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation (10.1 - 14460.28)
  com.apple.dt.DVTKit (10.1 - 14460.28)
  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation (10.1 - 14460.46)
  com.apple.dt.IDEKit (10.1 - 14460.46)
 +libswiftAVFoundation.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftCore.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftCoreAudio.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftCoreImage.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftCoreMedia.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftDarwin.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftDispatch.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftFoundation.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftIOKit.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftMetal.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftObjectiveC.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftQuartzCore.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftXPC.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
 +libswiftsimd.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
  com.apple.dt.DVTJRPC (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceControlServices (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.DebugSymbols (188 - 188)
  com.apple.XCWatchKit1Support (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.CoreSymbolicationDT (10.1 - 64460.7)
  com.apple.assetvalidation-plugin (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices (10.1 - 64460.16)
  +cvmsCodeSignObjqEZSGwI1dDAVVakc (???)
  com.apple.dt.instruments.DVTInstrumentsFoundation (10.1 - 64460.16)
  com.apple.Metal (1.0 - 1)
  +libswiftAppKit.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
  com.apple.IBCompilerPlugin (10.1 - 14460.31)
  +libswiftCoreData.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
  com.apple.SymbolicationDT (10.1 - 64460.9)
  com.apple.kperfdataDT (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.libktrace (1.0 - 271.200.30)
  com.apple.dt.instruments.DVTInstrumentsUtilities (10.1 - 64460.16)
 +libswiftos.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
  com.apple.xcode.compilers.coredata (12.1 - 14460.26)
  com.apple.dt.DVTServices (10.1 - 14460.28)
  com.apple.compilers.clang (12.1 - 14460.26)
  com.apple.dt.DVTPortal (10.1 - 1)
  com.apple.dt.XCTest (1.0 - 14460.20)
  com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceFoundation (10.1 - 1)
  com.apple.dt.XCTAutomationSupport (1.0 - 1)
 +libclang.dylib (1000.11.45.5)
  com.apple.dt.SourceKit (1.0 - 14460.2)
 +libLTO.dylib (1000.11.45.5)
  com.apple.dt.DVTAnalytics (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.dt.DVTDocumentation (1.0 - 14460.28)
  com.apple.DNTDocumentationModel (1.0 - 14460.6)
  com.apple.DNTDocumentationSupport (1.0 - 14460.6)
  com.apple.dt.XCTDaemonControl (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.LocFramework (2.0 - 42)
  com.apple.GLToolsMobileFoundation (1.0 - 24215)
  com.apple.dt.Xcode.DVTSourceControl (10.1 - 14460.4)
  com.apple.dt.XcodeKit (10.1 - 14460.46)
 +cvmsCodeSignObj9eLJFERShVqDWRe6 (???)
  com.apple.DNTSourceKitSupport (1.0 - 14460.6)
 +libswiftXCTest.dylib (4.2.1 - 1000.11.42)
  com.apple.dt.DVTAnalyticsClient (10.1 - 1)
  com.apple.DNTTransformer (1.0 - 14460.6)
  com.apple.dt.IDEProducts (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.dt.DVTDeveloperModeHelper (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.dt.instruments.DTGraphKit (10.1 - 64460.12)
  com.apple.dt.DebugHierarchyFoundation (1.0 - 2)
  com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorUtilities (581.2 - 581.2)
  com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimDeviceIO (581.2 - 581.2)
 +libMainThreadChecker.dylib (64460.8)
  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerFoundation (10.1 - 14460.32)
  com.apple.IDEWatchKit1SupportUI (10.1 - 14460.2)
  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDBService (10.1 - 14460.32)
  com.apple.DevToolsFoundation (12.1 - 14460.26)
 +liblaunch_sim.dylib (1336.220.5)
  com.apple.CoreSimulator (581.2 - 581.2)
  com.apple.dt.DebugHierarchyKit (1.0 - 2)
  com.apple.LLDBRPC (1.0 - 1000.11.38.2)
  com.apple.dt.XCTDaemonControlMobileDevice (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.DVTiPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient (10.1 - 14460.19)
  com.apple.XCWatchOSSupport (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.xcode.compilers.mlkit (12.1 - 14460.3)
  com.apple.dt.IBAutolayoutFoundation (10.1 - 14460.31)
  com.apple.dt.IBFoundation (10.1 - 14460.31)
  com.apple.AppleCV3D (1.21.3 - 1.21.3)
  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB (10.1 - 14460.32)
  com.apple.dt.IDE.Xcode3Core (10.1 - 14460.26)
  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore (12.1 - 14460.26)
  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsSupport (12.1 - 14460.26)
  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiOSSupportCore (10.1 - 14460.19)
  com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase (10.1 - 14460.19)
  com.apple.dt.XCLanguageSupport (10.1 - 14460.4)
  com.apple.xcode.compilers.intents (10.1 - 14460.4)
  com.apple.xcode.plug-in.CoreBuildTasks (12.1 - 14460.26)
  ...
  com.apple.HIServices (1.22 - 627.10)
  com.apple.LangAnalysis (1.7.0 - 1.7.0)
  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore (14.0 - 503.3)
  com.apple.QD (3.12 - 407)
  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework (8.0.6 - 8.0.6)
  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.14 - 1.14)
  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit (1.14 - 1.14)
  com.apple.AutomatorFramework (2.9 - 444.23.1)
  com.apple.CFNetwork (948.2 - 948.2)
  com.apple.Carbon (158 - 158)
  com.apple.CommonPanels (1.2.6 - 98)
  com.apple.HIToolbox (2.1.1 - 916.15)
  com.apple.help (1.3.8 - 66)
  com.apple.ImageCapture (9.0 - 1511.3)
  com.apple.ink.framework (10.9 - 222)
  com.apple.openscripting (1.7 - 176)
  com.apple.print.framework.Print (12 - 267)
  com.apple.securityhi (9.0 - 55006)
  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework (6.0.3 - 6.0.3)
  com.apple.Cocoa (6.11 - 23)
  com.apple.ColorSync (4.13.0 - 3331)
  com.apple.contacts (1.0 - 2876)
  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio (4.3.0 - 4.3.0)
  com.apple.CoreBluetooth (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.CoreData (120 - 862.7)
  com.apple.CoreDisplay (101.8 - 101.8)
  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1535.12)
  com.apple.CoreGraphics (2.0 - 1215.5)
  com.apple.CoreImage (14.0.0 - 643)
  com.apple.corelocation (2245.4.48.9)
  com.apple.CoreML (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.CoreMedia (1.0 - 2280.60.8.2)
  com.apple.CoreMediaIO (900.0 - 5019)
  com.apple.CoreServices (921.2 - 921.2)
  com.apple.AE (755.5 - 755.5)
  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1178.7 - 1178.7)
  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 284.15.2)
  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1239.200.9.10.1 - 1239.200.9.10.1)
  com.apple.LaunchServices (920 - 920)
  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 1191.23.3)
  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (920 - 920)
  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0)
  com.apple.coreservices.SharedFileList (71.9 - 71.22)
  com.apple.CoreText (352.0 - 584.9.1.2)
  com.apple.CoreVideo (1.8 - 0.0)
  com.apple.framework.CoreWLAN (13.0 - 1370.5)
  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework (10.14 - 207.50.1)
  com.apple.DiscRecording (9.0.3 - 9030.4.5)
  com.apple.DiscRecordingUI (9.0.3 - 9030.4.5)
  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.7 - 2.7)
  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1535.12)
  com.apple.GLKit (1.0 - 101)
  com.apple.GSS (4.0 - 2.0)
  com.apple.Bluetooth (6.0.8 - 6.0.8d20)
  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1483.200.35)
  com.apple.IOSurface (245 - 245)
  com.apple.ImageCaptureCore (1.0 - 1511.3)
  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.3.0 - 1771.2)
  libGIF.dylib (1771.2)
  libJP2.dylib (1771.2)
  libJPEG.dylib (1771.2)
  libPng.dylib (1771.2)
  libRadiance.dylib (1771.2)
  dylib (1771.2)
  com.apple.JavaScriptCore (14606 - 14606.1.17.40.4)
  com.apple.Kerberos (3.0 - 1)
  com.apple.LDAPFramework (2.4.28 - 194.5)
  com.apple.MapKit (1.0 - 1833.20.5.10.7)
  com.apple.MediaAccessibility (1.0 - 114.3)
  com.apple.MediaPlayer (1.0 - 1.0)
  com.apple.MediaToolbox (1.0 - 2280.60.8.2)
  com.apple.Metal (157.25 - 157.25)
  com.apple.MetalKit (1.0 - 107.4.1)
  com.apple.MetalPerformanceShaders.MPSCore (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.MetalPerformanceShaders.MPSImage (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.MetalPerformanceShaders.MPSMatrix (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.MetalPerformanceShaders.MPSNeuralNetwork (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.MetalPerformanceShaders.MPSRayIntersector (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.MetalPerformanceShaders.MetalPerformanceShaders (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.ModelIO (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.NetFS (6.0 - 4.0)
  com.apple.Network (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.OSAKit (1.5 - 107)
  com.apple.audio.OpenAL (1.8 - 1.8)
  unorm8_bgra.dylib (2.9.3)
  unorm8_rgba.dylib (2.9.3)
  unorm8_rgx.dylib (2.9.3)
  libcldcpuengine.dylib (2.9.3)
  com.apple.opencl (2.8.20 - 2.8.20)
  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory (10.14 - 207.50.1)
  com.apple.OpenDirectory (10.14 - 207.50.1)
  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib (17.0.26)
  libCoreFSCache.dylib (163.16)
  libCoreVMClient.dylib (163.16)
  libGFXShared.dylib (17.0.26)
  libGL.dylib (17.0.26)
  libGLImage.dylib (17.0.26)
  libGLU.dylib (17.0.26)
  com.apple.opengl (17.0.26 - 17.0.26)
  org.python.python (2.7.10 - 2.7.10)
  com.apple.QTKit (7.7.3 - 3026.1)
  com.apple.imageKit (3.0 - 1058)
  com.apple.PDFKit (1.0 - 721.1.1)
  com.apple.QuartzComposer (5.1 - 368)
  com.apple.quartzfilters (1.10.0 - 1.10.0)
  com.apple.QuickLookUIFramework (5.0 - 765.6)
  com.apple.quartzframework (1.5 - 21)
  com.apple.QuartzCore (1.11 - 658.2)
  com.apple.QuickLookFramework (5.0 - 765.6)
  com.apple.SafariServices.framework (14606 - 14606.1.17.40.4)
  com.apple.SceneKit (1.0 - 456.4)
  com.apple.ScriptingBridge (1.4 - 74)
  com.apple.security (7.0 - 58286.200.129.11.2)
  com.apple.securityfoundation (6.0 - 55185.200.14)
  com.apple.securityinterface (10.0 - 55109.200.5)
  com.apple.xpc.ServiceManagement (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.SpriteKit (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.17 - 1.17)
  com.apple.VideoToolbox (1.0 - 2280.60.8.2)
  libwebrtc.dylib (7606.1.17.40.4)
  com.apple.WebCore (14606 - 14606.1.17.40.4)
  com.apple.WebKitLegacy (14606 - 14606.1.17.40.4)
  com.apple.WebKit (14606 - 14606.1.17.40.4)
  com.apple.APFS (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.accessibility.AXCoreUtilities (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.AddressBook.core (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.AnnotationKit (1.0 - 232.3.15)
  com.apple.AppContainer (4.0 - 360.200.11.10.2)
  com.apple.AppSandbox (4.0 - 360.200.11.10.2)
  com.apple.AppSupportUI (1.0 - ???)
  com.apple.framework.Apple80211 (13.0 - 1375.5)
  com.apple.AppleFSCompression (96.200.2 - 1.0)
  com.apple.AppleIDAuthSupport (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.AppleJPEG (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.AppleLDAP (10.14 - 46.200.2)
  com.apple.aps.framework (4.0 - 4.0)
  com.apple.AppleSRP (5.0 - 1)
  com.apple.applesauce (1.0 - ???)
  com.apple.AppleSystemInfo (3.1.5 - 3.1.5)
  com.apple.AppleVAFramework (5.0.43 - 5.0.43)
  com.apple.AssertionServices (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.AuthKit (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.AuthKitUI (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.coreservices.BackgroundTaskManagement (1.0 - 57.1)
  com.apple.backup.framework (1.10 - ???)
  com.apple.BaseBoard (360.12.1 - 360.12.1)
  com.apple.BezelServicesFW (310 - 310)
  com.apple.bom (14.0 - 195)
  com.apple.CacheDelete (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.CalendarAgentLink (8.0 - 250)
  com.apple.ChunkingLibrary (194 - 194)
  com.apple.CommerceCore (1.0 - 708.0.29.2)
  com.apple.CommonAuth (4.0 - 2.0)
  com.apple.commonutilities (8.0 - 900)
  com.apple.framework.ConfigurationProfiles (11.0 - 1106)
  com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsFoundation (8.0 - ???)
  com.apple.contacts.ContactsPersistence (1.0 - ???)
  com.apple.CoreAUC (265.0.0 - 265.0.0)
  com.apple.CoreAVCHD (6.0.0 - 6000.4.1)
  com.apple.CoreAnalytics.CoreAnalytics (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.corebrightness (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.frameworks.CoreDaemon (1.3 - 1.3)
  com.apple.CoreEmoji (1.0 - 69.15.5)
  com.apple.CoreHandwriting (161 - 1.2)
  com.apple.CoreMediaAuthoring (2.2 - 958)
  com.apple.CoreNLP (1.0 - 130.15.15)
  com.apple.CoreOptimization (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.CorePDF (4.0 - 414)
  com.apple.CorePhoneNumbers (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.CorePrediction (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.CoreServicesInternal (355 - 355)
  com.apple.CoreSymbolication (10.0 - 64224)
  com.apple.CoreThemeDefinition (2.0 - 346.15)
  com.apple.coreui (2.1 - 498.23)
  com.apple.CoreUtils (5.7 - 570.33)
  com.apple.framework.CoreWiFi (13.0 - 1370.5)
  com.apple.CrashReporterSupport (10.13 - 1)
  com.apple.framework.DFRFoundation (1.0 - 206)
  com.apple.DSExternalDisplay (3.1 - 380)
  com.apple.datadetectors (5.0 - 382)
  com.apple.datadetectorscore (7.0 - 590.12)
  com.apple.DebugSymbols (183 - 183)
  com.apple.desktopservices (1.13 - ???)
  com.apple.DeviceLinkX (5.0 - 264)
  com.apple.diagnosticlogcollection (10.0 - 1000)
  com.apple.DiskImagesFramework (480.200.9 - 480.200.9)
  com.apple.DiskManagement (12.0 - 1517.1)
  com.apple.DisplayServicesFW (3.1 - 380)
  com.apple.SystemConfiguration.EAP8021X (14.0.0 - 14.0)
  com.apple.EFILogin (2.0 - 2)
  com.apple.Engram (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.vision.EspressoFramework (1.0 - 107)
  com.apple.vision.FaceCore (3.3.3 - 3.3.3)
  com.apple.framework.familycontrols (4.1 - 410)
  com.apple.GPUWrangler (3.22.9 - 3.22.9)
  com.apple.GenerationalStorage (2.0 - 285.101)
  com.apple.GeoServices (1.0 - 1365.20.5.10.5)
  com.apple.GraphVisualizer (1.0 - 5)
  com.apple.GraphicsServices (1.0 - 1.0)
  com.apple.Heimdal (4.0 - 2.0)
  com.apple.IASUtilities (1.0 - 497)
  com.apple.ids (10.0 - 1000)
  com.apple.idsfoundation (10.0 - 1000)
  com.apple.imfoundation (10.0 - 1000)
  com.apple.IOAccelerator (400.12.2 - 400.12.2)
  com.apple.IOPlatformPluginFamily (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.IOPresentment (1.0 - 37)
  com.apple.IconServices (262.1 - 365.2.1)
  com.apple.InternationalSupport (1.0 - 10.15.3)
  com.apple.IntlPreferences (2.0 - 227.15.2)
  com.apple.Jet (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.security.KeychainCircle.KeychainCircle (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.LanguageModeling (1.0 - 159.15.10)
  com.apple.Lexicon-framework (1.0 - 33.15.7)
  com.apple.LinguisticData (1.0 - 260)
  com.apple.LoggingSupport (1.0 - 906.200.52.10.1)
  com.apple.LoginUICore (4.0 - 4.0)
  com.apple.LookupFramework (1.2 - 246)
  com.apple.Mangrove (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.marco (10.0 - 1000)
  com.apple.MarkupUI (1.0 - 232.3.15)
  com.apple.MediaKit (16 - 903)
  com.apple.MediaRemote (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.MediaServices (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.spotlight.metadata.utilities (1.0 - 1191.23.3)
  com.apple.gpusw.MetalTools (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.MobileAssets (1.0 - 437.200.22.10.4)
  com.apple.mobiledevice (988.220.5 - 988.220.5)
  com.apple.MobileKeyBag (2.0 - 1.0)
  com.apple.Montreal (1.0 - 42.15.7)
  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework (2000.21 - 2000.21)
  com.apple.Navigation (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.NetAuth (6.2 - 6.2)
  com.apple.network.statistics.framework (1.2 - 1)
  com.apple.PackageKit (3.0 - 813.3)
  com.apple.PencilKit (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.PerformanceAnalysis (1.207 - 207)
  com.apple.PhoneNumbers (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.PhysicsKit (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.pluginkit.framework (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.PowerLog (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.ProtectedCloudStorage (1.0 - 1)
 (1 - 263)
  com.apple.QuickLookNonBaseSystem (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.QuickLookThumbnailing (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.ROCKit (17 - 17)
  com.apple.xpc.RemoteServiceDiscovery (1.0 - 1336.200.58.10.2)
  com.apple.RemoteViewServices (2.0 - 126)
  com.apple.xpc.RemoteXPC (1.0 - 1336.200.58.10.2)
  com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing (606 - 606.1.17.40.4)
  com.apple.SecCodeWrapper (4.0 - 360.200.11.10.2)
  com.apple.Sharing (1121.1 - 1121.1)
  com.apple.framework.sidecar-core (1.0 - 20)
  com.apple.performance.SignpostNotification (1.10 - 10)
  com.apple.SkyLight (1.600.0 - 336.42.5)
  com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore (5.0.20 - 5.0.20)
  com.apple.spotlight.index (10.7.0 - 1191.23.3)
  com.apple.StorageManagement (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.StreamingZip (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.Symbolication (10.0 - 64234.1)
  com.apple.framework.SystemAdministration (1.0 - 1.0)
  com.apple.TCC (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.TextureIO (3.8.1 - 3.8.1)
  com.apple.ToneKit (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.ToneLibrary (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 31)
  com.apple.UIFoundation (1.0 - 550.19)
  com.apple.URLFormatting (59 - 59.28)
  com.apple.Uninstall (1.0.1 - 211)
  libUAPreferences.dylib (361.33.1)
  com.apple.VectorKit (1.0 - 1361.20.5.10.3)
  com.apple.ViewBridge (379.1.1 - 379.1.1)
  libAWDSupportFramework.dylib (848)
  libprotobuf-lite.dylib (848)
  libprotobuf.dylib (848)
  com.apple.awd (1.0 - 930.8)
  com.apple.private.XprotectFrameWork.XprotectFramework (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.kperf (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.loginsupport (1.0 - 1)
  com.apple.login (3.0 - 3.0)
  com.apple.contacts.vCard (1.0 - ???)
  libAccessibility.dylib (2401.52.3)
  libCRFSuite.dylib (41.15.4)
  libChineseTokenizer.dylib (28.15.3)
  libCoreStorage.dylib (546.50.1)
  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (105)
  libFosl_dynamic.dylib (18.3.2)
  libMatch.1.dylib (31)
  libMobileGestalt.dylib (645.200.47.10.1)
  libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib (176)
  libSystem.B.dylib (1252.200.5)
  libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib (3595)
  libThaiTokenizer.dylib (2.15.1)
  libUniversalAccess.dylib (361.33.1)
  libapple_nghttp2.dylib (1.24.1)
  libarchive.2.dylib (54.200.2)
  libate.dylib (1.13.7)
  libauto.dylib (187)
  libboringssl.dylib (109.200.20)
  libbsm.0.dylib (39.200.15)
  libbz2.1.0.dylib (38.200.3)
  libc++.1.dylib (400.9.3)
  libc++abi.dylib (400.15)
  libcharset.1.dylib (51.200.3.10.1)
  libcmph.dylib (6.15.1)
  libcompression.dylib (52.200.11)
  libcoretls.dylib (155.200.6)
  libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib (155.200.6)
  libcrypto.35.dylib (22.200.2)
  libcrypto.42.dylib (22.200.2)
  libcsfde.dylib (546.50.1)
  libcups.2.dylib (462.5)
  libcurl.4.dylib (105.200.2)
  libdtrace.dylib (284.200.12)
  libdz.dylib (1.0.0 - 110.200.39.0.1)
  libedit.3.dylib (50.200.2)
  libenergytrace.dylib (17.200.1)
  libexslt.0.dylib (16.1)
  i.dylib (18.1)
  libgermantok.dylib (17.15.2)
  libheimdal-asn1.dylib (520.200.9)
  libiconv.2.dylib (51.200.3.10.1)
  libicucore.A.dylib (61105.0.1)
  liblangid.dylib (128.15.1)
  liblzma.5.dylib (10.200.3)
  libmecab.1.0.0.dylib (779.15.14)
  libmecabra.dylib (779.15.14)
  libncurses.5.4.dylib (53.200.3)
  libnetwork.dylib (1229.200.74.10.1)
  libnetworkextension.dylib (767.200.25.10.1)
  libobjc.A.dylib (744)
  libodfde.dylib (24.50.1)
  libpam.2.dylib (22)
  libpanel.5.4.dylib (53.200.3)
  libpcap.A.dylib (79.200.4)
  libquit.dylib (258)
  libresolv.9.dylib (65.200.2)
  libsandbox.1.dylib (851.200.80.11.2)
  libsasl2.2.dylib (211)
  libspindump.dylib (258)
  libsqlite3.dylib (274.15)
  libssl.35.dylib (22.200.2)
  libssl.44.dylib (22.200.2)
  libstdc++.6.dylib (104.1)
  libsysmon.dylib (100)
  libtidy.A.dylib (16.1)
  libusrtcp.dylib (1229.200.74.10.1)
  libutil.dylib (51.200.3)
  libxar.1.dylib (402.1)
  libxml2.2.dylib (32.5)
  libxslt.1.dylib (16.1)
  libz.1.dylib (70.200.4)
  libcache.dylib (81)
  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60118.200.5)
  libcompiler_rt.dylib (63.4)
  libcopyfile.dylib (146.200.1)
  libcorecrypto.dylib (602.200.31)
  libdispatch.dylib (1008.200.56)
  libdyld.dylib (620.3)
  libkeymgr.dylib (30)
  libkxld.dylib (4903.200.199.11.1)
  liblaunch.dylib (1336.200.58.10.2)
  libmacho.dylib (914)
  libquarantine.dylib (86.200.5.10.1)
  libremovefile.dylib (45.200.2)
  libsystem_asl.dylib (356.200.3)
  libsystem_blocks.dylib (73)
  libsystem_c.dylib (1272.200.20)
  libsystem_configuration.dylib (963.200.17)
  libsystem_containermanager.dylib (136.200.27)
  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (62)
  libsystem_darwin.dylib (1272.200.20)
  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (878.200.16)
  libsystem_info.dylib (517.200.7)
  libsystem_kernel.dylib (4903.200.199.11.1)
  libsystem_m.dylib (3158.200.6)
  libsystem_malloc.dylib (166.200.39.10.1)
  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (767.200.25.10.1)
  libsystem_notify.dylib (172.200.9.10.2)
  libsystem_platform.dylib (177.200.7)
  libsystem_pthread.dylib (330.200.30)
  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (851.200.80.11.2)
  libsystem_secinit.dylib (30.200.3)
  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (820.207.59)
  libsystem_trace.dylib (906.200.52.10.1)
  libunwind.dylib (35.4)
  libxpc.dylib (1336.200.58.10.2)


Model: VMware7,1, BootROM VMW71.00V.9694812.B64.1808210100, 4 processors, 3.05 GHz, 10.26 GB, SMC 1.16f8
Graphics: Display, 3 MB
Memory Module: RAM slot #0/RAM slot #0, 8 GB, DRAM, 0 MHz, VMware Virtual RAM, VMW-8192MB
Memory Module: RAM slot #1/RAM slot #1, 2 GB, DRAM, 0 MHz, VMware Virtual RAM, VMW-2048MB
Memory Module: RAM slot #2/RAM slot #2, 256 MB, DRAM, 0 MHz, VMware Virtual RAM, VMW-256MB
Memory Module: RAM slot #3/RAM slot #3, 8 MB, DRAM, 0 MHz, VMware Virtual RAM, VMW-8MB
Memory Module: RAM slot #4/RAM slot #4, 4 MB, DRAM, 0 MHz, VMware Virtual RAM, VMW-4MB
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: VMware Virtual SATA Hard Drive, 107.37 GB
Serial ATA Device: VMware Virtual SATA CDRW Drive
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: VMware Virtual USB Hub
USB Device: VMware Virtual USB Hub
USB Device: VMware Virtual USB Keyboard
USB Device: VMware Virtual USB Mouse
USB Device: USB Bus
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it detects if the user is on a virtual machine and they intentionally crash their software .. I had exactly the same problem when I updated xcode, so I returned to xcode 10.0 and it works. I use the latest version of mac os: Mojav and my system is up to date.